# How is ARP reply generated from Windows 10? Sending ARP req from embedded device through ethernet port to windows10 on laptop

Tags: networking, ping, arp, windows-networking, icmp

I want to send an ARP request using my embedded device through the ethernet cable to my laptop that has windows 10 on it.

I want to receive an ARP reply from windows back to my embedded device through the ethernet cable.

1. Will the ARP reply from widnows10 happen automatically if I just send an ARP request from my embedded device through the ethernet cable to windows10 on my laptop even while the wifi is running and my laptop windows10 is connected to the internet as well?
2. What software part of windows10 deals with generating the ARP reply? The network adapter driver?

I want to do the above process with ICMP ping req to the Windows 10 from my embedded device through the ethernet port to my laptop and receive the ICMP reply from the windows10 on my laptop.

I tried searching for these answers but couldn't find anything solid esp since I am new to this field.

Comment: Windows should, but you may need to create an allow rule in th firewall since Windows blocks all inbound traffic by default and I'm unsure if it applies to `arp` requests as well

Comment: @JW0914 The firewall doesn't block ARP requests (at least not by default). If that was the case, you would need to populate your ARP table manually to send IP packets to the receiver with that kind of firewall configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, the ARP reply will happen "automatically". Also, the ARP request will be sent "automatically" if you try to ping the target and its MAC is not in the ARP table yet. The ARP request is not sent to a specific device! An ARP request is sent as a broadcast to all devices in the subnet. Depending on your LAN configuration, the request can reach the target via LAN and WLAN (but only the one with the appropriate IP address will reply because the two network adapters will have different IP addresses).
2. To my knowledge, the ARP (protocol) is implemented in the TCP/IP stack.

Note: the question is not really on-topic here, it's not about a specific problem but rather general knowledge (as far as I can fathom it wouldn't have been a problem). So a different StackExchange site might be better suited. Also, you shouldn't put several questions into one post.

I would suggest reading about how ARP works, there are loads of articles/videos/animations with various levels of detail.

Comment: While I recognize and agree with your note, I know from experience how daunting it can be when you're facing a vast, veritable ocean of reading material on a subject you're not acquainted with.  Even if it's not really necessary according to site usage guidance, it may still be quite helpful to the OP if you perhaps linked one such resource/source you find particularly trustworthy or reputable for the topic?  Sometimes people aren't asking for the exact section and aisle number, but just need to know what direction the library is in.

Comment: @Arctiic I don't have any resources at hand, otherwise I would have posted a link.